# Writing a monad with out-of-band data (aka, composing monads in parallel)

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm currently writing a monad wrapping OpenGL called `GL` and I want to be able to query a computation to get a list of every texture it would possibly need.

Is this a solved problem? I'm having a lot of trouble writing the Monad instance for GL.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
-- GL should be able to be inspected for its HashSet without running the computation.
newtype GL a = GL (S.HashSet String) (IO a)

instance Monad (GL a) where
    return = GL S.empty . return -- Calls IO.return
    (>>=) (GL textures action) f = -- What goes here?
```

but am I barking up the wrong tree? It doesn't really work as a monad, since I have to query it before running it. What should I be using instead? I realllly like using do-notation.

I think this breaks down to: How do I compose two monads in parallel, then run them independently?

Comment: Have you considered wrapping `StateT (S.HashSet String) IO`? (Various state monad transformers are available.)

Comment: Because that still requires running the IO in order to get the textures the IO will be using. The whole point is to figure out in advance what textures are needed, and then load them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your GL type is that the "result of the computation" `a` is dependent on IO-actions, and therefore you can't implement a monad instance where you could compute the final texture HashSet without running the IO-actions.

The correct solution depends on the details on how you want to use the GL monad, but assuming that you can decide which textures to use without running IO-actions then you could a type like this

```
type GL a = WriterT (Set String) (Writer (IO ())) a
```

I.e. you use two nested writer monads, one for textures and one for accumulating the IO actions. The resulting monad stack is run in two phases, and you can get the final texture set without executing the IO actions.

Unfortunately, `Writer` only works for monoids so we need to define a `Monoid` instance for `IO ()` first.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Monoid

instance Monoid (IO ()) where
    mempty = return ()
    mappend = (>>)
```

Now, you can write a function that registers a new texture like this:

```
addTexture :: String -> GL ()
addTexture = tell . S.singleton
```

And another function that caches an IO action to be executed later

```
addIO :: IO () -> GL ()
addIO = lift . tell
```

Here's an utility function for running the GL monad

```
runGL :: GL a -> (a, Set String, IO ())
runGL gl = let iow = runWriterT gl
               ((a, textures), io) = runWriter iow
            in (a, textures, io)
```

This retuns a tuple with three elements: the result value from the computation, the set of accumulated textures and the accumulated io actions. Note that at this point, the `IO ()` value in the tuple just describes the action and nothing (e.g. drawing operations) haven't been executed yet.

I'm not sure if this covers your use-case, but hopefully it will give you some ideas on how to build a suitable monad stack. If you need more help, please provide some examples on how you want to actually use the `GL` monad.

Here's the complete code that I tested. Note that I used the type `Set` instead of `HashSet`, because according to the documentation of the [`hashmap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hashmap/1.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-HashSet.html) library, the `HashSet` name is deprecated.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Monoid
import Data.HashSet (Set)
import qualified Data.HashSet as S

instance Monoid (IO ()) where
    mempty = return ()
    mappend = (>>)

type GL a = WriterT (Set String) (Writer (IO ())) a

addTexture :: String -> GL ()
addTexture = tell . S.singleton

addIO :: IO () -> GL ()
addIO = lift . tell

runGL :: GL a -> (a, Set String, IO ())
runGL gl = let iow = runWriterT gl
               ((a, textures), io) = runWriter iow
            in (a, textures, io)
```

EDIT: You can also avoid the language extension if you wrap the IO effects in a newtype, as suggested by dave4420.

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Monoid
import Data.HashSet (Set)
import qualified Data.HashSet as S

newtype WrapIO = WrapIO { unwrapIO :: IO () }

instance Monoid WrapIO where
    mempty = WrapIO $ return ()
    WrapIO a `mappend` WrapIO b = WrapIO $ a >> b

type GL a = WriterT (Set String) (Writer WrapIO) a

addTexture :: String -> GL ()
addTexture = tell . S.singleton

addIO :: IO () -> GL ()
addIO = lift . tell . WrapIO

runGL :: GL a -> (a, Set String, IO ())
runGL gl = let iow = runWriterT gl
               ((a, textures), WrapIO io) = runWriter iow
            in (a, textures, io)
```

Comment: Or wrap the `IO ()` in a `newtype` and avoid `LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances`.

Comment: I read http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Monads that monad stacks impose a performance penalty. Is there any way to get these effects without it? Would just unrolling the stack be the way to go?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I just realized that what I want to do is infeasible with monads. With something like `do { x <- something; if x then y else z }`, a monad has no way of seeing "inside" the if to get data from both y and z. Thanks for your help! I doubt I'd have seen this without your example (and addIO's type).

Comment: @ClarkGaebel, unless you can see far enough into `something` to be able to evaluate `x` without running any `IO`.  That is what this answer is about.  Also, you don't need to use a monad stack; you can use a single `Writer` monad over the `(Set String, IO ())` product monoid.

Answer (score 3):

When you need to deduce things about your computations without actually running them, applicative functors tend to work better than monads, since their effects have static structure.

This is because with applicative functors, your method of sequencing actions is limited to `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, so the function in the first argument cannot change what side effects will happen, unlike `(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b` where the function argument is free to choose any side effect, so in order to extract information about those side effects, you have to evaluate the function, which in turn requires the result of the previous action and so on, until you're pretty much forced to run the whole thing.

A quick applicative implementation would look something like this:

```
data GL a = GL (S.HashSet String) (IO a)

instance Functor GL where
  fmap f (GL s x) = GL s (fmap f x)

instance Applicative GL where
  pure x = GL S.empty (pure x)
  (GL t0 f) <*> (GL t1 x) = GL (t0 `S.union` t1) (f <*> x)
```

Of course, avoiding monads means that you lose a bunch of control structures, so you'll have to provide replacement primitives in your functor if for example you want to allow conditionals, and make sure that you combine the information from the different branches correctly.

```
whenGL :: GL Bool -> GL () -> GL ()
whenGL (GL t0 cond) (GL t1 body) = GL (t0 `S.union` t1) (cond >>= \b -> if b then body else return ())
```

All in all, I think it should be possible to use applicatives to do what you're trying to do, but it might be somewhat cumbersome to program with. Especially because you lose out on things like do-notation and the various control structures in `Control.Monad`.

Comment: I'm okay with running "through" the monad. For example, I don't mind being stuck in an infinite loop if someone uses "forever" while finding what textures to load. However, I really need to use do notation here. The whole exercise gets ridiculously ugly otherwise. Is there a way to do it where instead of using (IO a) we use (a -> IO b)?

Comment: @ClarkGaebel: The problem is where do you get the `a`s from? If they are the results of `IO` actions, you're forced to run them. The main other approach I can think of is to essentially have a writer monad of `IO ()` actions, and that might work fine for OpenGL, as it's mostly write-only, but if you ever want to allow your computations to depend on the result of running an OpenGL action, you will either have to wrap that up as a primitive in your monad, or you're back to square one.

Comment: @ClarkGaebel: Though at that point, the writer monad is mostly just to abuse do-notation. What you've really got then is just a monoid.